# MongoDB CPU pegged; profiler returns "profile line too large"

Tags: mongodb

Every 6-12 hours, my MongoDB CPU is pegged (100% CPU usage).

I've enabled profiling. The last time returned this:

```
PRIMARY> db.system.profile.find().sort({$natural:-1});
{ "ts" : ISODate("2012-11-08T05:31:09.042Z"), "client" : "10.188.14.195", "user" : "", "err" : "profile line too large (max is 100KB)" }
```

Not very helpful, unfortunately.

I tried doing a db.currentOp(); while it was pegged and got this:

```
    {
        "opid" : 18256845,
        "active" : true,
        "lockType" : "write",
        "waitingForLock" : false,
        "secs_running" : 803653,
        "op" : "none",
        "ns" : "streamified.credentials",
        "query" : {

        },
        "client" : "",
        "desc" : "rsSync",
        "threadId" : "0x7f3b865f7700",
        "numYields" : 1
    },
```

Indicating that the query had been alive for over 800,000 seconds (FAR before the CPU was pegged). This query remained even after the CPU returned to normal, as well.

What is the best way to determine exactly which query (or, at the very least, which collection) is causing the CPU to become pegged?

Comment: do you have any queries to which you pass very long arrays (maybe find({key:{$in:[...]}}) where the array to $in has a very large number of elements?

Comment: I think the full line should be in the server log? (all operations > 100ms by default are logged)

Comment: @gregor hm, where can I find that?

Comment: The log path is specified with the --logpath switch, or if none is specified, the log goes to stdout.